Well Pressure Tank Problems
Just bought this property a few months ago. There is a 1500 gallon holding tank that gets supplied by the low flow well. I woke up to no more water in the holding tank last week. Tried troubleshooting with the well installer, installed a new capacitor, and since then the holding tank has been filling up very slowly.
My problem now is that the pressure tank still has no water in it. I can't figure out how to get the submersible pump in the holding tank to kick on. I've followed all youtube videos I can find on the subject, but even after I replaced the pressure gauge (had been frozen on 60psi), the new gauge reads 0psi, while the air pressure out of the top of the tank is showing 38psi after I added air.
Seems like the pressure switch is the next on the list to check for failure, but how would all three (capacitor, pressure gauge, and pressure switch) fail at the same time? Or how would the plumbing have been functioning properly long enough to empty the holding tank?
I am going to call the well installer to have them come fix it if I can't figure it out, but I'm trying to learn how it works so that I can take the best care of the system that I can.

Most water pumps need water to keep cool.  No water and they can burn/wear out fast.  The pressure gauge is more for you to check for proper pressure than for the pump to work.  The pressure switch is what turns the pump on/off when needed, some have a low/no pressure shut off feature to protect the pump/slow leaks.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
